# How to encrypt data in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

My research does show me that we cannot use Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) in SQL Azure.

In this regard, are they any options for encrypting data in SQL Azure.

I do not want to have this Encrypt/Decrypt operations at application level.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an in depth explanation about which kinds of encryption are and are not supported by SQL Azure on TechNet:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh351833.aspx

> SQL Azure does not currently support the standard data-encryption
>   mechanisms that SQL Server supports. These include transparent data
>   encryption, asymmetric keys, symmetric keys, and Transact-SQL
>   functions such as ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE and DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE,
>   CREATE/ALTER/DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY or CREATE/ALTER/DROP MASTER
>   KEY

TL;DR:  Application level is probably your only choice right now

Comment: Hello Tom, that article is way back in July 2011. So I am wondering if get something new, which does support some kind of ancryption.

Comment: Even on MSDN TDE is still listed as a current limitation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx

Comment: TDE is implemented as of Apr 2015.

Answer (score 9):

TDE is now supported in Azure: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/TDE-in-Azure-SQL-Database

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948096.aspx

Comment: Just keep in mind that as of 5/19/2015 it's still in PREVIEW, which means it's not recommended for production environments.

Comment: ...and it's [out of preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-transparent-data-encryption-general-availability/) since October 2015. :)